# Confocal Microscopy

Tags: import, image

Is it possible to direcly import Nikon ND2 files (e.g  Confocal microscope 2D or 3D stacks  files)?

Otherwise how can we import TIFFs of 3D stack and process it as a single "entity" so to speak?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know about that file type specifically, but look into `Image3D` and `Image3DSlices`

Comment: From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TIFF.html), it looks like you can import a multipage TIFF as an `Image3D`. Regarding the ND2 format, I highly doubt anyone has implemented that, so you would need use a library in another language (e.g. C, Java) and write some additional code to plug it in to *Mathematica*, if you want this functionality badly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Why not?  If [this](exists) ...  But I agree, look for ways to implement the importer yourself.  If you do, consider sharing it.

Comment: Thank you for your positive feeback. I am working on it and will be glad to share if I get it to work.

Comment: [NIS-Elements-Viewer](http://www.nikoninstruments.com/Products/Software/NIS-Elements-Advanced-Research/NIS-Elements-Viewer) loads ND2 files and can export them to TIFF, which can be imported by Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs your link was malformed. Did you find a package capable of loading the ND2 files?

Comment: @OleksandrR. No, just some packages for equally specialized formats ... there seem to be ImageJ plugins, which can maybe be called with JLink.  But the simplest is to just convert to TIFF as you suggested.

Comment: The ImageJ distribution FIJI contains Bioformats, which seems to be supported by many vendors. We use it with files from from another microscope manufacturer to convert them to TIFF.  Import[] usually works very well.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your insighful suggestions. @ Dr.Stelzer. I am a Mathematica neophyte and was wondering wther you can kindly point me to specific litterature (including yours if possible) that employed Mathematica in processing light and/or electron microscopy. Many thanks.

Comment: The Bio-Format command line tools http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5.1/users/comlinetools/  were most helpful to us. You need JRE, and calls of `bfconvert` or `showinf` can be made via `Run`.